# Overriding property with dynamic property variable not working PHP 7.0

Tags: php, php-7

When switching from PHP 5.6 to 7.0, I need to do it based on this script. I am trying to apply rewrite rules in WordPress as follows but a strange PHP issue is encountered. Dynamic properties made via variable are not working in PHP 7.0.

```
$rule = [   'name' => 'profile',
            'rule' => 'author_base',
            'rewrite' => 'profile',
            'position' => 'top',
            'replace' => true,
            'dynamic' => true
         ];
global $wp_rewrite;
global $wp;
$wp->add_query_var($rule['name']);
if(isset($rule['replace']) && $rule['replace']) {
    var_dump($rule['rule']); // author_base
    $wp_rewrite->$rule['rule']=$rule['rewrite']; // this doesn't work
    $wp_rewrite->author_base=$rule['profile']; // this works
    var_dump($wp_rewrite->$rule['rule']) // return null => BAD
    var_dump($wp_rewrite->author_base); // returns 'author' => OK
    // In PHP 5.6 Works both including $wp_rewrite->$rule['rule']
} else {
    add_rewrite_rule($rule['rule'], $rule['rewrite'], $rule['position']);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's one of the [B.C](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) of php7.

> Indirect access to variables, properties, and methods will now be evaluated strictly in left-to-right order, as opposed to the previous mix of special cases.

```
| Expression          | PHP 5 interpretation  | PHP 7 interpretation  |
|---------------------|-----------------------|-----------------------|
| $foo->$bar['baz']() | $foo->{$bar['baz']}() | ($foo->$bar)['baz']() |
```

So, change

```
$wp_rewrite->$rule['rule']=$rule['rewrite'];
var_dump($wp_rewrite->$rule['rule']);
```

to

```
$wp_rewrite->{$rule['rule']}=$rule['rewrite'];
var_dump($wp_rewrite->{$rule['rule']});
```

Comment: Yes, working, noticed that this also works in PHP 5.6 with TH `{ }`